# How to add Tkinter button that allows the user to play their own music?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Just a quick question: In a game, I'm making, I want the player to be able to pick an audio file from his/her computer and play it in the game and I'm not all that sure how to do it. I want them to be able to open a browse files screen (default file explorer) and then select a music file and play it as bgm, all by the click of a button.

Now I know Tkinter doesn't support sound but I don't care how the program runs. As long as I can fit it into my code. If you need my code, it's here: https://github.com/SeaPuppy2006/FruitClicker (I'm using my windows build at the moment). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `playsound` module and use a thread to prevent block:

```
from playsound import playsound
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import threading
def f():
    def play():
        pathname = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        playsound(pathname)
    threading.Thread(target=play).start()

root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Button(root,text="playsound",command=f).grid()

root.mainloop()
```